# Overridden virtual function not called from thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am writing a base class to manage threads. The idea is to allow the thread function to be overridden in child class while the base class manages thread life cycle. I ran into a strange behavior which I don't understand - it seems that the virtual function mechanism does not work when the call is made from a thread. To illustrate my problem, I reduced my code to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct B
{
    thread t;
    void thread_func_non_virt()
    {
        thread_func();
    }

    virtual void thread_func()
    {
        cout << "B::thread_func\n";
    }

    B(): t(thread(&B::thread_func_non_virt, this)) { }
    void join() { t.join(); }
};

struct C : B
{
    virtual void thread_func() override
    {
        cout << "C::thread_func\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c;   // output is "B::thread_func" but "C::thread_func" is expected
    c.join();
    c.thread_func_non_virt();   // output "C::thread_func" as expected
}
```

I tried with both Visual studio 2017 and g++ 5.4 (Ubuntu 16) and found the behavior is consistent. Can someone point out where I got wrong?

**== UPDATE ==**

Based on Igor's answer, I moved the thread creation out of the constructor into a separate method and calling that method after the constructor and got the desired behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior. There's a race on `*this` between `thread_func` and `C`'s (implicitly defined) constructor.

Comment: On `*this` rather, `this` is not being modified or shared.

Comment: @n.m. Corrected.

Comment: I feel I missed some lecture about "this" pointer. Would you kindly elaborate more or point me to the right article to read?

Comment: Inside `B`'s constructor, the object is of type `B`. if you call `thread_func` directly from `B` constructor, you'll reliably call `B::thread_func` version. Only when `B` constructor returns and `C` constructor starts running does the object turn into type `C`, and calling `thread_func` dispatches to `C::thread_func`. Now, in your example, these two things happen simultaneously - the run-time type of the object changing from `B` to `C`, and `thread_func` call from another thread needing to determine this run-time type in order to dispatch to the right function implementation. Hence the race.

Comment: @Igor, just for my understanding, does the vtable gets overwritten after B constructor returns and C constructor starts running? Or it is a compiler implement ion detail we should not count on?

Comment: The concept of vtable is an internal implementation detail; the C++ standard doesn't mention it. Practically speaking, all major compilers I'm familiar with do implement virtual inheritance with the help of a vtable. Yes, typically, vtable pointer gets updated first thing by each constructor in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

struct B
{
    thread t;
    void thread_func_non_virt()
    {
        thread_func();
    }

    virtual void thread_func()
    {
        cout << "B::thread_func\n";
    }

    B(B*ptr): t(thread(&B::thread_func_non_virt, ptr))
    {
    }
    void join() { t.join(); }
};
struct C:public B
{
    C():B(this){}
    virtual void thread_func() override
    {
        cout << "C::thread_func\n";
    }
};



int main()
{
    C c;   //  "C::thread_func" is expected as expected
    c.join();
    c.thread_func_non_virt();   // output "C::thread_func" as expected
}
```

Comment: While this code may/may not solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations.

Comment: Have you tried this? It won't even compile, and when you fix that, it will exhibit [the exact same race condition](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdbfbd666cf96545).

Comment: This code does compile and the output is as expected. I feel this answer and Igor's one both point to the same explanation.

Comment: I forgot to mention the code compiles in VS. Like @n.m. suggested, it may be just luck of race condition or a particular compiler implementation. Without future understanding, I cannot conclude the current answer is the right solution.

Comment: You don't have C deriving from B. I have no idea what kind of broken compiler allows this code.

Comment: Different class contain different virtual function tables, but it is not good for constructors to call virtual functions，I'm sorry, my English is not very good